# Installing Tripwire

Tags: networking, security

I just installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 15 and while I installed it I did not connect to the Internet. I have read you should install tripwire first thing after a fresh install and before you even connect to the Internet.

- Now my question is would it be safe/ok to connect to the Internet and
  just install tripwire?
- Can I also download any dependencies that may be required?

I don't want to sound too paranoid but I just want the best Tripwire setup. Any suggestions is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect to Internet to install it, unless you know how to install a package from offline repository!

So I suppose you have to connect to Internet and take it easy and don't be paranoid.

You can install Tripwire easily using:

```
sudo apt-get install tripwire
```

This should resolve any dependency problems